# Display attribute of error messages only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-errors

In rails, when an attributes has more than 1 error, then errors messages will show up like:

```
- Image size cant greater 1MB
- Image should be 1024x768 max
```

But i want modify it to this format:

```
Image:
 -Cant greater 1MB
 -Should be 1024x768 max
when upload.
```

Is anyone know how to do it, please help me. Thankyou your guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the html you are using to print the errors

```
<% @image.errors.messages.each do |attribute, messages| %>
  <%= attribute.to_s.titleize %>
  <% messages.each do |message| %>
    <%= "- #{message}" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will give you output:

```
Image:
 - Cant greater 1MB
 - Should be 1024x768 max
```

Comment: but how can i display attribute in other language like japaness?

Comment: Make use of I18n `<%= t(:attribute) %>`

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you're currently using something like this to render your error messages:

```
# erb
<% model.errors.full_messages.each |m| do %>
  <li><%= m %></li>
<% end %>
```

Rails does give you a granular breakdown of validation errors in `errors`, if you choose to use it. For example:

```
model.errors[:image]
# => [ "can't be greater than 1MB", "should be 1024x768 max" ]
```

Will give you just the errors for `image`.

Bearing this in mind, you could try something like this:

```
# erb
<% model.errors.each do |attr, messages| %>
  <li>
    <%= attr %>:
    <ul>
      <% messages.each do |m| %>
        <li><%= m %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: but how can i display attribute in other language like japaness?